# Typed Italian Dependencies Parser

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

*Is there any Italian Dependecies Parser like the Stanford one?* 
 
I searched over the internet, but I didn't find much.
I've already experienced with the Stanford Dependencies to build typed dependencies like `nsubjpass(submitted, Bills)`  (https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml). 
 I found out the *Universal Dependencies* and in its documentation page at http://universaldependencies.org/ there are various kinds of UD Treebanks, one of which is the *italian UDTreebank*. The problem is that I don't know how to use it to get typed dependencies of a phrase. 
 So, is there an open source implemented italian dependencies parser? If not, has someone experience in such a field and knows how to use the italian UDTreebank to create a parser in Java? (Alternatively other language is fine as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tint](http://tint.fbk.eu/) provides a full Java-based pipeline for Italian NLP, including doing dependency parsing. It is open source, and based around [CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/), but provides Italian models and additional annotators.